# How do I safely remove a Hadoop datanode for maintenance?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to take a single machine out of a Hadoop cluster temporarily.

Most documentation says take it out of by adding it to the yarn and dfs .exclude files. I don't want to add it to the dfs.exclude and yarn.exclude files and decommission it with `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes`, though, because I want to take it out, make some changes to the machine, and bring it back online as soon as possible. I don't want to copy hundreds of gigabytes of data over to avoid under-replicated blocks!

Instead, I'd like to be able to power off the machine quickly while making sure:

- The cluster as a whole is still operational.
- No data is lost by the journalmanager or nodemanager processes.
- No Yarn jobs fail or go AWOL when the process dies.

My best guess at how to do this is by issuing:

```
./hadoop-daemon.sh --hosts hostname stop datanode
./hadoop-daemon.sh --hosts hostname stop journalnode
./yarn-daemon.sh --hosts hostname stop nodemanager
```

And then starting each of these processes individually again when the machine comes back online.

Is that safe? And is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is safe.  The namenode will start re-replicating the 'missing' blocks if the datanode is down for more then 10 minutes (by default).  Once it comes back online, it will report it's blocks and the namenode will stop re-replicating the blocks that are no longer under-replicated.